# modify scrum template in TFS 2010 after project is created

Tags: tfs, scrum, tfs-to-tfs-migration-tool

I have created a new team project using sfts v3.0 project template.  Later I have realized that we need to customize scrum template (add some new status).  How can I upgrade the scrum template once team project has been created.  Can I modify the template and overwrite files to location where it is on TFS 2010 server?

The new project I have created is entirely blank and I am running migration tool to migrate source code from tfs 2008 to tfs 2010 and I don't want to interrupt that process.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the *Process Editor* of the [TFS Power Tools](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/c255a1e4-04ba-4f68-8f4e-cd473d6b971f).

[Here's a guide](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms243782.aspx) how to use it.